Are all L2s rollups?
It seems when people refer to L2s, they are always referring to rollups.
So, is the term interchangeable?

No, not all L2s are rollups.
Rollups are the most popular kind of L2, but there are many kinds of L2s.
What is an L2?
An L2 is a "Layer Two" and is any system built on top of an existing L1 blockchain.

Rollups: These are perhaps the most popular type of L2 solutions. Rollups work by processing and storing transaction data on a separate layer but submit transaction data back to the main chain.
State Channels: This solution involves two or more participants exchanging state updates off-chain securely.
Plasma: An older L2 solution where a child blockchain runs under the main Ethereum blockchain, reporting back periodically. Plasma chains can handle large volumes of transactions and defer to the main chain for security.
Oracles: Any device that connects blockchain with real world/external data and computation.

You'll notice that I did not include sidechains like Polygon PoS. Sidechains have a loose definition of chains that are alternates to another blockchain. For example Polygon PoS is a sidechain of Ethereum.
